# Quelle est la différence entre la déshydratation et la déshumidification ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage, définition, différence

Bonjour

Je crois comprendre que la déshumidification a pour but de diminuer la teneur en humidité tandis que la déshydratation consiste à diminuer la teneur en eau. Mais il me semble que l'humidité de l'air se quantifie en fonction de la vapeur d'eau contenue dans une masse d'air sec donc je ne vois pas bien la différence... Y'a-t-il une différence technique entre de l'air déshumidifié et de l'air déshydraté ?

Merci

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language. Ta question n'est pas vraiment une question sur la langue Française mais c'est une question de physique. si tu comprends l'anglais peut-être que tu pourrais regarder du côté de  [Physics Stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). Il y a certainement des gens assez calés en physique pour répondre ici mais la réponse débordera aussi le cadre de ce site.

Comment: Bonjour, merci je prends note du site, désolée pour le hors sujet.

Comment: De rien. Je précise que ce n'est pas moi qui ai moinssoyé la question, je tiens à dire publiquement que je trouve cet acte très inélégant vis à vis d'un nouveau venu sur le site. La question était certes hors cadre  certes hors sujet mais il suffisait d'en demander la fermeture sans mettre de note négative.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec @None. Je ne comprendrai jamais les gens qui cliquent sur "--" sans rien dire, sans prévenir, on dirait qu'ils se vengent de je ne sais quoi...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Déshydrater, c'est faire baisser la proportion d'**eau** (liquide) contenue dans n'importe quelle substance, éventuellement jusqu'à une disparition quasi totale de toute trace d'eau.

Déshumidifier est une opération plus spécifique qui consiste à réduire la proportion de **vapeur d'eau** contenue dans l'air (humidité = [degré hygrométrique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humidit%C3%A9_relative)). La vapeur d'eau est un gaz.

Comment: D'accord je comprends merci pour votre réponse